# How to set different markers on single series line chart?

Tags: telerik, devexpress, fusioncharts, zingchart, wijmo5

I have different libraries which I am trying to figure our which one works with multiple markers on same single series line chart.

Lets say 1 series is there v = [11, 12, 43, 21, 22]

I want point 11 to be rectangular, 12 to be concentric circle, 43 to be square and 21 and 22 be circle.

I tried going through the docs but could not find anything.

Please let me know if its possible on ZingChart, devexpress chart, telerik chart, flot chart, fusion chart or wijmo chart angularJs libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with ZingChart very easily. We have a `jsRule` which allows you to define a function. Within the function you return our `marker` syntax to change the style of the `marker` or node as its most common name.

Another way is to explicitly code the syntax within our `rules` which is a hardcoded form of `jsRule`.

I have added both in the following demo. You can add any attributes from the [marker](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/plot/marker/) object into the following syntax.

```js
/*
 * callback argument format:
 {
   "id":"myChart",
   "graphid":"myChart-graph-id0",
   "graphindex":0,
   "plotid":"",
   "plotindex":0,
   "nodeindex":7,
   "key":7,
   "scaleval":7,
   "scaletext":"7",
   "value":85,
   "text":"%v",
   "ev":null
 }
 */
window.changeMarker = function(e) {
  // this function is called once for every node
  var returnObj = {
    type: 'square'
  }
  
  if (e.nodeindex % 2 == 0) {
    returnObj.type = 'star5';
    returnObj.backgroundColor = 'black';
    returnObj.size = 10;
  }
  // you can put any sort of logic to transform the marker nodes
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  return returnObj;
}
var myConfig = {
  type: 'line', 
 series: [
  {
   values: [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85],
   marker: {
     jsRule: 'changeMarker()'
   }
  },
  { // you can also explicitly set them with rules
   values: [135,142,167,189,125,134,167,185],
   marker: {
     rules: [
       {
         rule: '%i == 0',
         type: 'square'
       },
       {
         rule: '%i == 1',
         type: 'triangle',
         size:10
       },
       {
         rule: '%i == 2',
         type: 'star5'
       },
       {
         rule: '%i == 3',
         type: 'diamond',
         backgroundColor: 'black'
       },
       {
         rule: '%i == 4',
         type: 'plus',
         size:15
       },
       {
         rule: '%i == 5',
         type: 'star3',
         size:12
       },
       {
         rule: '%i == 6',
         type: 'rpoly6',
         size:9
       },
       {
         rule: '%i == 7',
         type: 'star4',
         size: 6
       }    
     ]
   }
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

References:

https://blog.zingchart.com/2016/05/09/make-a-custom-tooltip/?q=make%20a%20custom%20tooltip%20in%20zingchart%20using%20functions

https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/create-javascript-rules/

https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/plot/marker/

https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/plot/rules/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was looking for exactly same thing.